# Folders inside src/Controller/ folder

Tags: component, joomla-4.x, controller

I know that you can add a controller into the `src/Controller/` folder directly, and Joomla automatically recognizes it as a controller class, and you can route to it using either

```
?controller=controllername
?task=controllername.task
```

But this doesn't seem to work if the controller class is in a directory, for example: `src/Controller/User/ControllerName.php`.

How do I use folders?

**Edit**: The reason for adding folders is because there are many controllers, and having them grouped together is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, in your Controller folder:

```
class BranchController extends FormController
{
    public function update_localgroup() {
        $file = JPATH_COMPONENT . '/src/Controller/Branch/localgroups.php';
        include $file;
    }
    public function update_region() {
        $file = JPATH_COMPONENT . '/src/Controller/Branch/regions.php';
        include $file;
    }
}
```

I do this quite a lot to group umpteen sub-controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom implementation of `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Factory\MVCFactoryInterface` or extend the provided `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Factory\MVCFactory` class.
From your examples there is no clear connection between the URL parameters and class names so you'd have create something like a mapping table.